PHP CI4: How do I call a function without waiting for return?
I have a long running task that is called in the controller, but I don't want the user to have to wait for a long time for the page to load. What is the recommended way to call the function asynchronously?
I researched this topic, but there seems to be so many ways to do it, and all of them are quite complicated, or compromise on the security.
CI4 v4.3.5
PHP v8.2.21
I have tested the spatie/async package, which seemed the simplest to use, but it only lets you run multiple threads at the same time, but you have to wait for them to finish to continue.
I also tried calling my function using a spark command, but you still have to wait for it to finish.
I want to run 1 task separately so that the user can load their page faster.

You could maybe use ajax. Or completely split the job off and run it via cron or something- maybe triggered by a user request. Hard to advise without more context of the job and what it's for

It's a mailing system that takes user input and sends it to many other users. I was thinking to let the put the sending in a async function so that the user can continue to do other activities while the emails are being sent.

That's ideal for a background cron job. Have something which acts as a queue - e.g. a tasks table in your database, or an actual message bus system perhaps, and the frontend can add jobs to that when the user requests it. The cron job runs frequently and looks for new tasks to do, from the queue. It takes the next task and processes it. Optionally you can build a mechanism to notify users when the job is complete too, if needed. This architecture takes all the long-running processing away from the webserver, so the application can continue with other work

This is a common pattern, as are many other options. Did you do any meaningful research into this subject before posting here? Unsurprisingly you are a long way from being the first person  to want to do something like this.

I was under the impression that cron tasks were done in console, and run at a specific date/time. I want them to run when I trigger it, is it possible to do so with cron? I am unfamiliar with it.

Read my description again - I described how the frontend would trigger the task to take place. The cron script would run very frequently- e.g. every minute or two, potentially, and the first thing it does is check if there are any new tasks in the queue. If there are, it processes the next one immediately.

Ah I get what you mean now. Since I will need to write the cron task in a seperate php file, do you have any recommendations on how to call the function? Since I am using controller and models in CI4 i would prefer to do the processing in it, but I am unsure in how to call the CI4 function from within the cron task.
My first thought is to use exec() to run the ci4 spark command, but there seems to be a lot of concerns on the security on it.

I doubt that's a good idea. Now it's a cron job your controller should not come into it. I'm not a codeigniter expert so I'm not sure if there's a good way to re-use your models from a command line script or not.  You could also look at the queue library proposed below in case it integrates better and provides similar functionality.

Will definitely do. Thanks so much for your help!

The standard, simplest way is to use a cron job; not sure what you mean about security, it is just as secure as running your code via a browser.  As you say there are many answers here about this already - here's one about CI specifically.  If you need something more sophisticated, eg many different jobs running at many times, maybe look into a queue system - but for simple jobs I'd suggest that's overkill.

Handling long-running tasks asynchronously in CodeIgniter 4 (CI4) is to use a queue system. This approach is scalable, reliable, and allows you to run tasks in the background without blocking the main process.
Summary with Example:

Install a Queue Library (e.g., php-resque):

Install php-resque or another queue library to manage background jobs.
2. Add a Job to the Queue:
In your controller, when a user triggers a long-running task, you add a job to the queue instead of processing it immediately.
